# How to display a form after clicking a button in Angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, angularjs-directive

I have a button on my page and when I click it I want my form to display right below it.
I also want the number of times I click the button, it should show that many forms.

I am new to **Angular 9** and have no clue how to display a form on the same page as the button.

Code for the button:

```
<html>
  <body ng-app>
    <button type="submit" (click)="onClickForm" > Next </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code for the form:

```
<html>
<form>
  First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
</form>
```

Comment: What angular version are you using?

Comment: I am using v9.1.8

Answer (score 2):

***THE SOLUTION IS FOR ANGULARJS***

**in view**

```
<html>
  <body ng-app>
      <button type="submit" ng-click="onClickForm()" ng-show="!showForm"> 
         Next 
      </button>        
      <form ng-show="showForm">
         First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
      </form>  
   </body>
</html>
```

**in js Controller**

```
$scope.showForm= false;

$scope.onClickForm = function(){
    $scope.showForm = true;
}
```

Comment: This will not work, as OP is using Angular 9, not AngularJS

Comment: @palaѕн you are right ... in the original title said Angular JS ... I edited the answer just in case some users need angular js ...

Comment: No problem. This is a basic answer for AngularJS but just wanted to mention the OP's requirement.

Comment: Thank you. This was extremely helpful. God bless

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is what you are looking for.**

You can use [`Reactive Forms`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and `FormArray` if you want a array of `First Names` or `users`. you can find a clear tutorial [here](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/). working StackBlitz can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarraybesthansand).

- in your ts file

> ```
> import { Component, VERSION,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
> import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'my-app',
>   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
>   styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
> })
> export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
>   name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
>   userForm: FormGroup;
>   users: FormArray
>   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
>
>   ngOnInit(): void{
>     this.userForm = this.fb.group({
>       users: this.fb.array([])
>     })
>   }
>
>   createUserForm(){
>     return this.fb.group({
>       firstname: ''
>     })
>   }
>
>   adduser(){
>     this.users = this.userForm.get('users') as FormArray;
>     this.users.push(this.createUserForm());
>   }
> }
> ```

- in your html file

> ```
> <button (click)="adduser()"> next </button>
>
>
> <form [formGroup]="userForm">
>   <div formArrayName="users" *ngFor="let item of userForm.get('users')['controls']; let i = index;">
>       <div [formGroupName]="i">
>           <input formControlName="firstname" placeholder="firstname">
>     </div>
>       </div>
> </form>
> ```